# How to make text mask underlying widgets?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Doing some Tk canvas graphics I get this behaviour:

[image]

The upper '|' is not visible because of the line below crossing it. I would like to mask an area below the text to make sure it is always visible, and could not find a simple way to do this in Tk.

Q: What are my options to masking graphics below a **canvas** text widget?

Comment: Do you mean a `text` **widget** (which is really heavyweight hypertext editing component) or a `text` **canvas item** (can support a little bit of editing, but is much less complex really; supports rotation in 8.6)? The title says one thing, but your solution implies the other…

Comment: @DonalFellows Canvas item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented one possible solution for it.

After creating the text widget I create a rectangle with background fill put. The rectangle is also added to *a tag whose name is derived from the text widget name*:

```
set anno [$canvas create text $acoords -text $text -justify $ajust]
set bgfill [$canvas itemcget background -fill]
set anno_bg [$canvas create rectangle {0 0 0 0} -tags ${anno}.bg -fill $bgfill -width 0]
$canvas raise $anno_bg tmplt_annotation; # tmplt_annotation is a layer of sorts
$canvas raise $anno $anno_bg
```

Then on updating the position of the text widget I set the rectangle coordinates using its tag handle to the text bounding box, plus a little extra for border:

```
  set box [$canvas bbox $awidget]
  $canvas coords ${awidget}.bg [- [lindex $box 0] 1] [- [lindex $box 1] 2] [+ [lindex $box 2] 1] [+ [lindex $box 3] 5]
```

What I don't like about this is using tags for finding the rectangle through the text widget name. Then again could be because of my inexperience with tags.

Comment: Put a common tag on the text and the background so you can then treat them as one.

Comment: And, assuming you're talking about text canvas items (and not text widgets), putting a rectangle (or other masking item) underneath is exactly the simplest fix. For a more subtle effect, put an image with transparency (by copying stuff from a PNG) underneath to get a less stark hiding of what's underneath; that's a bit more complicated to get right, but can look awesome (when you notice it at all)…